# Read URL Encoded parameters PHP

Tags: java, php, url, url-encoding

I am trying to send data to my php script, but I have encoded the URL with my Java application:

```
final URL url = new URL(base + URLEncoder.encode(params, "UTF-8"));
```

And this makes the following:

```
http://www.example.com/send.php?username%3DTest%26runtime%3D15
```

I use `$_GET['username']` and `$_GET['runtime']` and when I try to echo those, it prints nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `url` should have `=` after `username`

`http://www.example.com/send.php?username=%3DTest%26runtime%3D15`

And then you can use `$_GET['username']`. you have problem with creating url in java, not php.

maybe your java code should be like this

```
final URL url = new URL(base + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(params, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: @KevinS you can't encode `=`. It's must be `=` not %3D, you can check it with `var_dump($_GET)` and see it.

Comment: @cooPer unless he wants to parse the query string manually :)

Comment: @iam-decoder we can do lot of thing, we should do it?